# bspwm closing windows issue

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal

Hello I recently got bspwm as my WM and, I am super confused on how to close windows i can close all windows with (super + w) except the last one, where instead of actually closing the window the cursor just turns into a X. if someone could help It would help.

Thanks

Comment: Check http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/bspwm.1.html and https://github.com/baskerville/bspwm/wiki .

Answer (score 0):

About the cursor turning into an X when you're not over a program, just add this to your bspwmrc (by default: `~/.config/bspwm/bspwmrc`):

```
bspc config focus_follows_pointer true
```

About the keybindings, make sure you have sxhkd installed, as BSPWM doesn't have a way to manage keybinds and sxhkd is a daemon to supply that. I'll recommend that you check on someone sxhkd configs on Github to have an idea on how to configure sxhkd.
However, just in case you don't find an example rc, check if your sxkhdrc is same as the default:

```
# close and kill
super + {_,shift + }w
bspc node -{c,k}
```